# Python 3.x and TestLink xmlprc

Tags: python, xml-rpc

Appreciate your helping first, I am new for the python 3.x.
When I try to use Python 3.x to parse the testlink xmlprc server. I got below error, but I can run the code under Python 2.x, any idea?

```
import xmlrpc.client

server = xmlrpc.client.Server("http://172.16.29.132/SITM/lib/api/xmlrpc.php") //here is my testlink server
print (server.system.listMethods()) //I can print the methods list here
print (server.tl.ping()) // Got error.
```

Here is the error:

```
['system.multicall', 'system.listMethods', 'system.getCapabilities', 'tl.repeat', 'tl.sayHello', 'tl.ping', 'tl.setTestMode', 'tl.about', 'tl.checkDevKey', 'tl.doesUserExist', 'tl.deleteExecution', 'tl.getTestSuiteByID', 'tl.getFullPath', 'tl.getTestCase', 'tl.getTestCaseAttachments', 'tl.getFirstLevelTestSuitesForTestProject', 'tl.getTestCaseCustomFieldDesignValue', 'tl.getTestCaseIDByName', 'tl.getTestCasesForTestPlan', 'tl.getTestCasesForTestSuite', 'tl.getTestSuitesForTestSuite', 'tl.getTestSuitesForTestPlan', 'tl.getLastExecutionResult', 'tl.getLatestBuildForTestPlan', 'tl.getBuildsForTestPlan', 'tl.getTotalsForTestPlan', 'tl.getTestPlanPlatforms', 'tl.getProjectTestPlans', 'tl.getTestPlanByName', 'tl.getTestProjectByName', 'tl.getProjects', 'tl.addTestCaseToTestPlan', 'tl.assignRequirements', 'tl.uploadAttachment', 'tl.uploadTestCaseAttachment', 'tl.uploadTestSuiteAttachment', 'tl.uploadTestProjectAttachment', 'tl.uploadRequirementAttachment', 'tl.uploadRequirementSpecificationAttachment', 'tl.uploadExecutionAttachment', 'tl.createTestSuite', 'tl.createTestProject', 'tl.createTestPlan', 'tl.createTestCase', 'tl.createBuild', 'tl.setTestCaseExecutionResult', 'tl.reportTCResult']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:\SQA\Python\Testlink\Test.py", line 5, in <module>
  print (server.tl.ping())
 File "C:\Python31\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1029, in __call__
  return self.__send(self.__name, args)
 File "C:\Python31\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1271, in __request
  verbose=self.__verbose
 File "C:\Python31\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1070, in request
  return self.parse_response(resp)
 File "C:\Python31\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1164, in parse_response
  p.feed(response)
 File "C:\Python31\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 454, in feed
  self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've seen this message before, it happened because the contents of the transported data wasn't escaped for XML transport.  The solution was to wrap the data in an *[XMLRPC Binary object](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xmlrpc.client.html#binary-objects)*.

In your case, you don't control the server side, so the above isn't a solution for you but it may suggest what the actual problem is.

Also, the Python 2 versus Python 3 difference suggests that there is a text/bytes issue at work.

To help diagnose the issue, set `verbose=True` so you can see the actual HTTP request/response headers and the XML request/response.  That may show you what is at `line 2: column 0`.  You may find that the issue may be with the PHP script not wrapping up binary data in base64 encoding as required by the [XMLRPC spec](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html).

Comment: Hi,Ray, Thanks, I add verbose = True and I can see a Fatal error:[[[[[header: Date header: Server header: X-Powered-By header: Content-Length header: Content-Type header: X-Pad body: b"<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'Hello!.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php:.:/opt/lampp/htdocs/SITM/lib/functions/:/opt/lampp/htdocs/SITM/third_party/') in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/SITM/lib/functions/common.php</b> on line <b>102</b><br />\n" ]]]]

Comment: It look like I missing the file, but this file is automatic load.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , I find out all the methods list, only 'tl.sayHello', 'tl.ping','tl.about' has this problem, and all of them are pass a string with a PHP automatic loader empty file *.class.php to the parser, other methods are pass a xml file. So I give up to use those methods and the script works fine.